# WordPress post/page show only if user is authenticated using external API

Tags: wordpress, rest

I have some accounts on the external site, and i want for WordPress to ask user to login first if they view the selected post/page.

The login guard is not WordPress user data login, but my external site login API. Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: This is far too broad a question. This can be build but you need to provide more details. What is the external API? How do you authenticate in the current site?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Its a bit complex process, but certainly possible.

Comment: @janw basically the external API is my current running system, with many users registered there. I want WordPress content to only be seen by my registered users. So login process, authenticated by external site, store token then can view the WordPress page. If token expired then users need to do login process again.